# Electrode: Keeping Jest test files out of /lib on build

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, walmart-electrode

**How do I keep the `*.spec.js*` and `*.test.js*` files out of the `/lib` directory?**

I feel like maybe I missed something really dumb setting up Jest tests. I've put the tests in the `/src` like [the docs indicate](https://docs.electrode.io/intermediate/component-archetype/unit-tests#jest) and is  typical for Jest testing, but doing a build copies the test files to the `/lib` directory.

I've looked for ways to override this behavior, but it seems like this bit in the `electrode-archetype-react-app/arch-clap.js` prevents any config around this.

```
"build-lib:client": { 
    desc: false, 
    dep: [
        ".clean.lib:client", 
        ".mk.lib.client.dir", 
        ".build.client.babelrc"
    ], 
    task: mkCmd(`babel`, 
                `--source-maps=inline 
                   --copy-files 
                   --out-dir ${AppMode.lib.client}`, 
                `${AppMode.src.client}` ) 
}
```

I've made a little demo app to illustrate this.

https://github.com/snekse/electrode-jest-build-config-example

**Switch to the proper branch**

```
git checkout electrode-jest-docs-issue
```

**Build the project**

```
yarn install && yarn cleanBuild
```

**Check for test/spec files in /lib**

```
yarn hasLibTest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Electrode team felt this was a bug.  I submitted a PR to address the issue which has already been merged and published.

If you include [electrode-archetype-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electrode-archetype-react-app) `^5.4.14`, it should prevent the test files from ending up in your `/lib` directory.

https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode/pull/998